# Why normalize only data for CDSs for PCA?

Tags: risk, value-at-risk, pca, cds

I'm reading a [Credit Suisse Research Report](https://doc.research-and-analytics.csfb.com/docView?language=ENG&format=PDF&document_id=1001969281&source_id=emcmt&serialid=Coz8ZUCgL92gmMydSBULHAsCBlmogDBprg0kSAhRLCk%3D) on PCA. 
The report says that to preprocess the data, you should "Centre data (and normalize when considering CDS data)."

Why would you only normalize data for CDS, and not for other products?

Answer (score 1):

The choice of normalization depends on your data set:

Without normalization : variable with high variance will have more impact on the PCA. You will have size effects. For exemple if you have one variable in meters and the other one in kilometers the one in meters will have way more impact.

To avoid that you can normalize but now every variable will have the same power of explnanation. Noise may have a lot of power explanation.

Normalising some variable but not the others could be interpreted as a way to reduce the impact of a high variance variable without changing the order of power of explanation of the others.

By doing this, the explanation power of the normalized variable will be arbitrary changed with respect to the order of power explanation of the others variable. Plus that this hybrid pre-process is shady to non-statistician people. I think this should be concidered bad practice.